# Proof concerning sufficient condition for an extreme value of the multivariable function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Actually, I have the problem with one part of it (condition of nonexistence of an extreme value).

Let's assume that $f(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ is continuous and has continuous first and second derivatives in the neighbourhood of the stationary point $(x_1^0, x_2^0, \ldots, x_n^0)$.

From the Taylor theorem
$$
\Delta=f(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) - f(x_1^0, x_2^0, \ldots, x_n^0) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,k=1}^n f_{x_ix_k}\Delta x_i \Delta x_k,
$$
where $\Delta x_i = x_i - x_i^0$ and all the derivatives are taken in some point 
$$
(x_1^0+\theta\Delta x_1, x_2^0 + \theta \Delta x_2, \ldots, x_n^0 + \theta \Delta x_n),\quad \theta\in (0,1).
$$

Let's define
$$
a_{ik} = f_{x_i x_k}(x_1^0, x_2^0, \ldots, x_n^0), \quad i,k=1,2,\ldots,n.
$$
From the continuity of the derivatives, we can write
$$
f_{x_ix_k}(x_1^0+\theta\Delta x_1, \ldots, x_n^0 + \theta \Delta x_n) = a_{ik} + \alpha_{ik},
$$
where $\alpha_{ik}\to 0$ when $\Delta x_1 \to 0, \ldots, \Delta x_n \to 0$.
Then, we can write
$$
\Delta = \frac{1}{2} \left[ \sum_{i,k=1}^n a_{ik}\Delta x_i \Delta x_k + \sum_{i,k=1}^n \alpha_{ik}\Delta x_i \Delta x_k \right]
$$
Now, let's assume that the first quadratic form in the [...] is indefinite. We have to show that the function $f$ doesn't have the extreme value in $(x_1^0,\ldots,x_n^0)$.

Let's assume that for some $\Delta x_i = h_i$ our form is negative
$$
\sum_{i,k=1}^n a_{ik}h_i h_k <0
$$
and put
$$
\Delta x_i = h_i t,\quad t\neq 0.
$$
It represents moving the point $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ on the straight line connecting $(x_1^0, x_2^0, \ldots, x_n^0)$ and $(x_1^0 +h_1, x_2^0 +h_2, \ldots, x_n^0 + h_n)$. Then we have
$$
\Delta = \frac{t^2}{2} \left[ \sum_{i,k=1}^n a_{ik}h_i h_k + \sum_{i,k=1}^n \alpha_{ik}h_i h_k \right].
$$
We have to show now that for the sufficiently small $t$, our $\Delta$ is always negative. Of course, because $t\to 0 \implies \Delta x_i \to 0 \implies \alpha_{ik}\to 0$, the second sum goes to $0$. However, for the same reason so is the first sum. How to show that the expression in the brackets [...] is always negative?

If we can show it, then it's just the matter of taking some $\Delta x_i = h_i^\ast$ for which the form is positive and the reasoning is the same. We  then know that arbitrarily close to the stationary point, function $f$ takes both greater and smaller values than $f(x_{1}^0,\ldots, x_n^0)$ and thus cannot have an extreme value there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'm a little embarrassed, but I will answer my question nonetheless. I thought that $h_i$ change when $t$ is changing but clearly they are just some constants corresponding to some specific values $\Delta x_i$ so they don't change with $t$ and the first sum doesn't go to $0$ when $t\to 0$. The rest of reasoning is correct.